# How to select states for a Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filters

I'm a bit rusted on Kalman filters. I read about them about 10 years ago.

So here it goes

I have this equation which I'm aware is non-linear. This a simplified equation a DC-link capacitor with input power increasing the voltage of the capacitor and output power (V*Iout) decreasing the DC-link voltage.

$$ VC\frac{dv}{dt} = P_{in} - V*I_{out} $$

I measure directly V and $P_{in}$. I think $P_{in}$ should be input "u". I think V should be a state of the Kalman Filter and I would like to estimate $I_{out}$ too. That's where I'm stuck at the moment. I got the feeling that $I_{out}$ should be a state, but I'm kind of lost. Where should I go from here. $I_{out}$ will likely jump from 0 to 100 Amps and the back to 20 Amps in real-life situations.

Regards

Edit : I'm aware that I could estimate Iout without using a Kalman filter, I'm just curious.

Comment: Do you have an expression for $d/dt I_{out}$?

Comment: No, it's more of a disturbance.